# How to force UI updates in the browser while lengthy javascript calculations are in progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have one place in a web app where I'm doing a lot of calculations in JavaScript *in the browser*.  They may take from a less than a second to about a minute to run, and I would like to show a progress dialog during this step, but the dialog doesn't show until after my calculations are complete.  I started by just trying to show a jquery dialog:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="startwork" value="Start working">

<div id="dialog" title="My dialog">
    This should show up immediately on clicking the button.
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function() {

    $("#startwork").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        // Do some lengthy calculations
        for (var i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
            var foo = Math.random();   
        }
        $("#dialog").dialog("close");
        alert("done");
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

});
```

What can I do to force the UI to update prior to the start of the calculations and at defined intervals during the calculations?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Wrap your lengthy calculations inside a `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
// some length calculations
}, 0);
```

There should be no more script after `setTimeout`.

```
$(function() {

    $("#startwork").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        setTimeout(function() {
            // some length calculations
            for (var i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
                var foo = Math.random();   
            }
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            alert("done");
        }, 0);
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I built a queue of work tasks and used setTimeout to initiate each item in the queue in sequence.  Works nicely.

Comment: @ExceptionSlayer timeouts queue work items. if anything is queued to run before the timeout, that item (usually) executes first - including painting the UI. this is a good tutorial on timeouts: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show a dialog while calculations are occuring, use *setTimeout* to call the long calculations after showing the dialog. If you want to show a progress bar, then you'll have to use a sequence of *setTimeout* calls at convenient points during the processing. When one ends, it updates the progress bar and calls the next one untill everything is done.

However, while any particular script is running, the UI will be blocked.