# Jquery redirect to login page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've been using ASp.NET to handle post back operations, but i'm now starting to plug in more and more cool JQuery stuff. I use e.PreventDefault on all my methods, to stop .aspx pages from reloading on click of buttons, or paging.

I've run into a problem, where i need to force the end user back to the login page when the cookie time out has reached.

How can I check that this has expired, and then force the users to login again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989734/how-to-force-ui-updates-in-the-browser-while-lengthy-javascript-calculations-are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery's library doesn't contain any functions to look at COOKIES but here is a plugin that you can add that handles COOKIES variables.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Comment: I think your link is missing.