# Why is CSS animation delayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to set an "updating" image spinning during a long-running JS function.
I am adding a class ("spinning") using JQuery which I have defined in my CSS to trigger the animation - this works fine when run on it's own. However, when I follow the addClass with a long-runnning JS function call, there is a delay in the animation, even though the class is applied instantaneously.

Can someone show me where I am going wrong & how to get the animation to initiate before the long-runnning function is run?

This JSFiddle illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/gLas4k23/2/
- the spinning starts before "doSomething" completes, but after a noticeable delay which is absent if the call to doSomething is not present.

```
html:
<div id='updateIcon' class='update'></div>

css:

.update {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url("http://s24.postimg.org/4psxulnkh/update_light.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.update.spinning {
    -webkit-animation: spinner 1s infinite linear;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

JS:
$('#updateIcon').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('i have been clicked');
    $('#updateIcon').addClass('spinning');
    doSomething();
})


function doSomething(){
 console.log('doing something')

 for(var i=0;i<20000;i++){
     console.log('waiting');
 }

}
```

Comment: Probably because a loop of 20000 iterations calling `console.log()` is blocking the thread

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989734/how-to-force-ui-updates-in-the-browser-while-lengthy-javascript-calculations-are explains why. Updated example http://jsfiddle.net/gLas4k23/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `for` loop has to finish before the animation starts. Once you remove that loop, the animation starts immediately.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/gLas4k23/4/

I think you'll have to use the `setTimeout()` function to get your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the Fiddle, the problem is with your `console.log`. It delays the process. I have updated the fiddle. [Try 
Now](http://jsfiddle.net/gLas4k23/8/)

Comment: The console.log in a loop was there to illustrate the problem and simulate a long-running function.